# Datepicker jquery parsedate language

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

So The problem is my language works for my calendar but not for the parsedate
Below is my code (i made this like the example on the site).

```
$(function(){
                $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['nl-BE']);
                // Datepicker
                $('#datepicker').datepicker({

                    firstDay: 1,
                        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                    inline: true,
                    onSelect: function(dateText){
                    var datez = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy',dateText,{shortYearCuroff: 20, dayNamesShort: $.datepicker.regional['nl-BE'].dayNamesShort, dayNames: $.datepicker.regional['nl-BE'].dayNames, monthNamesShort: $.datepicker.regional['nl-BE'].monthNamesShort, monthNames: $.datepicker.regional['nl-BE'].monthNames}).toString();
                    var value = datez.split('00:00:00');
                    generatexml(dateText,value);

                    }

                });
            });
```

This results in my language of the calendar changed but not the language in parsedate? Any idea what i did wrong?

> Sat Mar 24 2012

Is the result given, i have also tried to put the daynumber before the month witouth any result :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok Soo you currently are using the wrong function you want formatDate.

After lots of research you want to use that instead and also change your `var datez`

**From**

```
var datez = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy',dateText,{shortYearCuroff: 20, dayNamesShort: $.datepicker.regional['nl-BE'].dayNamesShort, dayNames: $.datepicker.regional['nl-BE'].dayNames, monthNamesShort: $.datepicker.regional['nl-BE'].monthNamesShort, monthNames: $.datepicker.regional['nl-BE'].monthNames}).toString();
```

**To**

```
var datez = $.datepicker.formatDate('D M d yy',new Date(dateText)).toString();
```

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/edhkB/).

Comment: Thx, but I'm still wondering why the parsedate didnt work... Its taken from an example on the official website o.O

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your working code, but in the example given, changing "shortYearCuroff" to "shortYearCutoff" would help.